# What is the most efficient way to get this kind of matrix from a 1D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with total `4950` values like:

```
0.012345678912345678
```

I read the file using:

```
a = numpy.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype=str, delimiter=',') # a.shape = (4950L, 1L) #dtype=str as I don't want to compromise accuracy
#say a == ['0.000000000000000001', -'0.000000000000000002', ...., '0.000000000004950']
```

What I am trying to achieve is to obtain a matrix `b` of size `(100L, 100L)` whose:

1. Upper triangular values are filled with values in numpy array 'a'.
2. Lower triangular values are filled with values in numpy array 'a' but multiplied by -1.
3. The diagonal consists of zeros only.

Example(The accuracy matters):

```
array = ['1','2','-3','-5','6','-7'] # In reality the data is up to 18 decimal places.

final_matrix = [
               ['0','1','2','-3'],
               ['-1',0,'-5','6'],
               ['-2','5','0','-7'],
               ['3','-6','7','0']
               ]
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the format in your file?  One row, one column, multiple columns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234965/copy-flat-list-of-upper-triangle-entries-to-full-matrix - a similar recent question `Copy flat list of upper triangle entries to full matrix`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but this seems pretty efficient.

```
import numpy

# create some random data for testing
sz = 100
a  = numpy.random.random(sz*sz/2 - sz/2).astype('S50')

# convert back to float for a test on minus signs,
# as it would be done if a is read as string values
amins = numpy.where(a.astype(float) <= 0, "", "-")

# get the values without minus signs
aplus = numpy.char.lstrip(a, "-")

# addup to negated string values
aminus = numpy.char.add(amins, aplus)

# create an empty matrix
m = numpy.zeros(shape=(sz,sz), dtype='S51')
# ids of the upper triangle
u_ids = numpy.triu_indices(sz,1)
# set upper values
m[u_ids] = a
# switch coordinates to set lower values
m[u_ids[1],u_ids[0]] = aminus
# fill diag with zeros
numpy.fill_diagonal(m, numpy.zeros(sz).astype('S51'))


print m
```

Comment: There are various ways of using the `np.tri...` functions to fill upper and lower triangular arrays.  But it sounds like the OP is worried more about the long integers (whether as a numeric type or string).

Comment: great. Last line  can simply be  `m-m.T` .  data seems to be float64 ?

Comment: Yes, according to the docs, the default dtype of numpy.zeros is float64.

Comment: Question about trying to go larger than `np.float64`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820829/cannot-use-128bit-float-in-python-on-64bit-architecture

Comment: Updated the example to use strings

Comment: @Niemerds **numpy.char.add** will just add a '-' sign. Suppose if the value is '-0.001020001111114444' then it will make it '--0.001020001111114444'.

Comment: your right. Again edited the example to account for double "-"

Comment: @Niemerds Sir, you are amazing. Just one thing left. It is putting '-' sign with '0.0'. Thanks