# Converting 1D numpy array into top triangle of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to take a 1D numpy array containing 171 values and place these values into the top triangle of an 18X18 matrix?

I feel like I should be able to use np.triu_indices to do this somehow but I can't quite figure it out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [What is the most efficient way to get this kind of matrix from a 1D numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862571/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-this-kind-of-matrix-from-a-1d-numpy-array) and [Copy flat list of upper triangle entries to full matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234965/copy-flat-list-of-upper-triangle-entries-to-full-matrix)

Roughly the approach is

```
result = np.zeros(...)
ind = np.triu_indices(...)
result[ind] = values
```

Details depend on the size of the target array, and the layout of your values in the target.

```
In [680]: ind = np.triu_indices(4)
In [681]: values = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)[ind]
In [682]: result = np.zeros((4,4),int)
In [683]: result[ind]=values
In [684]: values
Out[684]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 15])
In [685]: result
Out[685]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15]])
```